# Original assembly location in .NET 5.0 Linux with Single-File Executable

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, .net-5

I've found numerous answers relating to .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5.0 on *Windows*, but so far have been unable to find how to get the original assembly location under .NET Core on *Linux* when using a single-file executable.  Given that the systems behave differently, I think this is probably a bug in .NET 5, but I need a workaround in the mean time.  Note that in my scenario, the current directory is *not* where the original executable is located, even if I don't change it, and I have no control over it (and that's a hack anyway--the purpose of current directory is *completely* different).  Here's the actual output of a test program under this scenario with the properties and functions that have been suggested in all the other posts I've been able to find so far:

```
Directory.CurrentDirectory()=/home/ec2-user/source
typeof(Program).Assembly.Location=/root/.net/Test/jwaxs3pc.bdp/Test.dll
typeof(Program).Assembly.GetFiles() [0].Name=/root/.net/Test/jwaxs3pc.bdp/Test.dll
typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().CodeBase=file:///root/.net/Test/jwaxs3pc.bdp/Test.dll
AppContext.BaseDirectory=/root/.net/Test/jwaxs3pc.bdp/
Directory.GetParent(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FullName=/root/.net/Test/jwaxs3pc.bdp
```

I need to find the *original* code location, not the location the single-file executable was decompressed into.  How do I get this most basic of all information?  Is there not a platform and setting-independent way to do this (there *really* should be)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you publish your app as single executable file, some APIs related to Assembly will not work, and this is not a bug.

It is documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#api-incompatibility

There you'll see in that table that `Assembly.Location` will always return empty string when running in a single executable file.
As suggested in that doc, you could call `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` and evaluate the value of the first item in the string array result.

Comment: Hmmm.  Looks like there are two bugs then.  If you read my output, Assembly.Location does *not* in fact return an empty string, and AppContext.BaseDIrectory does *not* return the path of the executable as that page suggests.  I guess I really am on the bleeding edge here.  That page is dated 15 Oct 2021, one day before my question, and wouldn't have been indexed when I was looking.  Thanks for the GetCommandLineArgs() workaround.

Comment: @James you're welcome :) I'm glad my answer helps you.